# Quicksort with pivot as middle instead of 1st index sorts incorrectly

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, pivot, quicksort

Just a quick one. I'm struggling to make this code work when the pivot is the middle value. I know it works when the pivot is the leftmost value. Any help please?

```
public class Quicksort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 4 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        sort(numbers);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }

    public static void sort(int[] number) {
        quicksort(number, 0, number.length - 1);
    }

    public static void quicksort(int[] array, int left, int right) {
        int lowest = left, highest = right;

        if (right - left >= 1) {
            int pivot = array[(left + right) / 2];
            // works when pivot = array[left];
            while (lowest < highest) {
                while (array[lowest] <= pivot && lowest <= right && highest > lowest) {
                    lowest++;
                }
                while (array[highest] > pivot && highest >= left && highest >= lowest) {
                    highest--;
                }
                if (highest > lowest) {
                    swap(array, lowest, highest);
                }
            }
            swap(array, left, highest); // problem area?
            quicksort(array, left, highest - 1);
            quicksort(array, highest + 1, right);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    public static void swap(int[] array, int index, int index1) {
        int temp = array[index];
        array[index] = array[index1];
        array[index1] = temp;
    }

}
```

the output for this is

```
    [1, 3, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 4] //unsorted
    [2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 8] //wrongly "sorted"
```

Comment: I suggest you find the simplest example where this fails and step through the code in your debugger (this is what I would have to do)

Comment: This seriously looks like some homework... In any case learn debugging to find what went wrong. If you don't know any debuggers use the most crude way printf things.

Comment: The thing is I literally have been spending hours on this and can't get the 1 to change to the beginning

Comment: What is the justification for the `swap` call labeled "problem area"? That looks like it was incorrectly included from a different partitioning algorithm.

Comment: @rici cause i tried running through the code and i think its that area that messes it up.. but the problem is i don't know which variables to swap there

Comment: I didn't mean "what is the justification for the comment". I meant, "what is the justification for the swap". The comment seems totally justifiable to me. If I write a line of code, I need to be able to explain *why*.

Comment: @rici i was trying to swap the pivot with the final index of the array value

Comment: But what you do is swap the first element of the range, which is not the pivot. Anyway, that's not the correct statement of the goal. The goal is to put the pivot element at the correct place. Which implies that it was not at the correct place. If you start with the pivot at the left and don't move it during the scan, then it is still at the left at the end of the scan, so it is not at the correct place. Does that reasoning have any relation to your scan? If so, it is not obvious. Hence my original question to you.

Comment: I tried leaving out the `swap()` call in question, got correct sorting in some cases and incorrect in some. I think the swap is sometimes warrented, but haven’t investigated deeply.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion by Peter Lawrey, I first observed that your program sorts two numbers correctly. Then tried with three:

```
    int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 6 };
```

After your while loop you have

- `left` = 0
- `lowest` = 2
- `highest` = 1

In this case your comment `problem area?` seems correct sonce you are swapping the numbers 1 and 3, thus bringing them out of order.

In general, after your loop you know that `array[left..lowest - 1]` are `<= pivot` and `array[highest + 1..right]` are `> pivot`, but if `lowest == highest` I don’t think you can be sure whether `array[highest]` belongs in one part or the other, so you don’t know whether to swap it into the left part.

By the way, you have the same problem with `int pivot = array[left];`. Try `int[] numbers = { 3, 1, 6 };`, the result is `[3, 1, 6]`.